# Extracting RGB from a pixel without color object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rgb

I am trying to extract R G B values from a pixel in the following code:

```
for ( int i=0; i < pixeldata.length; i++)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = bmd.Scan0+i;
        byte* pixel = (byte*)ptr;

        //here is the problem :O

        float r = pixel[1];
        float g = pixel[2];
        float b = pixel[3];
     }
....
```

where bmd is an array of pixels data:

```
BitmapData bmd = source.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, source.PixelFormat);
```

and source is the Bitmap of my input, which is an image. 
I am trying to avoid the use of Color object. I have already done that and it works, I want to use this other way, but the issue is that ptr is a number and I have to extract the R G B from it.

Comment: That depends on the pixel format.

Comment: Just curious, why avoid the Color object?

Comment: Let's say that it is a challenge from my CTO. It is very easy to do it with Color object and I have done it, but the method above is supposed to give you the right answer, but the result is wrong by a big margin.

Comment: most of the answers were not correct. Why should I accept them?

Comment: @user843681 - Then feel free to add the correct answer and accept that.

Comment: when your dealing with accessing pixels via pointers the order is B-G-R...

Comment: When calculating the pixel address you must use the BitmapData Stride and Width.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution that gives you the right answer.

```
Bitmap source = new Bitmap(image);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height);

            BitmapData bmd = source.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            int totalPixels = rect.Height * rect.Width;
            int[] pixelData = new int[totalPixels];
            for (int i = 0; i < totalPixels; i++)
            {
                byte* pixel = (byte*)bmd.Scan0;
                pixel = pixel + (i * 4);

                byte b = pixel[0];
                byte g = pixel[1];
                byte r = pixel[2];

                int luma = (int)(r * 0.3 + g * 0.59 + b * 0.11);
                pixelData[i] = luma;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a format that stores R, G, and B as one byte each linearly in memory in that order, the code to extract the RGB values should look like

```
byte r = pixel[0];
byte g = pixel[1];
byte b = pixel[2];
```

Note that the index offset begins at 0, and that the values returned are `byte` not `float` (though you can certainly cast if you wish).

Additionally you would have to increment *i* by 3 rather than 1 because 3 adjacent bytes represent a single pixel.

You would be wise to test that `source.PixelFormat` indeed uses the format you are assuming.

You also have to compile with the /unsafe switch in order to use pointers in C#.

**UPDATE**

Per @Don's comment as well as your own, the order in linear memory would be ABGR.  That means the code would be:

```
for ( int i=0; i < pixeldata.length; i+=4)
{
    IntPtr ptr = bmd.Scan0+i;
    byte* pixel = (byte*)ptr;

    byte a = pixel[0]; // You can ignore if you do not need alpha.
    byte b = pixel[1];
    byte g = pixel[2];
    byte r = pixel[3];
}
```

Comment: I think the first index is Alpha, which is of no use for me.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions and the result is still very wrong.

Comment: @user843681: If you have alpha as well, then your indices were correct but you must increment `i` by 4 each iteration.  Also see @Don's comment about pixel order in linear memory.  Updated my answer to reflect both.

Comment: I implemented this and it didn't give the correct answer. In the debug mode I picked up a random value. Using Color object, I get these values for one specific pixel:  ARGB=(255,133,133,129), while for the same pixel using the pointer method I get these values: r=255, g=130, b=126. ptr value by the way is 116916268 for this particular pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was interesting, and I have written some code to play with. Assuming that your image has pixels in format `Format24bppRgb` (more info about formats here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx). This format store B, G, R values in 24 bits one after another.

Below code which will parse some `d:\\24bits.bmp` image from your hard drive and creates new identical one `"d:\\24bits_1.bmp"` using information B, G, R information from bytes array of first image data.

```
unsafe private static void TestBMP()
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("d:\\24bits.bmp");

    // Ensure that format is Format24bppRgb.
    Console.WriteLine(bmp.PixelFormat);

    Bitmap copyBmp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Copy all pixels of initial image for verification.
    int pixels = bmp.Height * bmp.Width;
    Color[,] allPixels = new Color[bmp.Height, bmp.Width];
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
            allPixels[i, j] = bmp.GetPixel(j, i);

    // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        bmp.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    byte* stream = (byte*)ptr;

    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            int byteIndex = y * bmpData.Stride + x * 3;

            byte r = stream[byteIndex + 2];
            byte g = stream[byteIndex + 1];
            byte b = stream[byteIndex];

            Color c = allPixels[y, x];
            if (r != c.R || g != c.G || b != c.B)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This should never appear");
            }
            copyBmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
        }

    // Save new image. It should be the same as initial one.
    copyBmp.Save("d:\\24bits_1.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me test it tonight and will get back to you. Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: Hi Sergey, I went through your code and I have to tell that unfortunately your code will not pass my criteria as it uses GetPixel method, which is a very slow method ( I mean really slow!). Also, using two loops makes the code harder to become Parallel later. What I have done is to place all values in one array of the size height*width. And then reading from this array and extracting RGB from each pixel byte. I will work more on this and if I can properly solve it, I will post my solution.

Comment: @user843681 - my code use GetPixel() just to show that it is correct. Actual algorithm does not need GetPixel(), it gets values directly from byte array.